# How should i edit manifest for jar?

Tags: java, mysql, jar, applet, manifest

I create an application - Instant Messenger - with connecting to MySQL and it required MySQL Driver, so I enclose this external library and this program works well. But I'd like to re-create this app as Applet and archive it to .jar
How could I edit manifest for enclosing the Driver to Applet?

I know I can use (for desktop app) Class-Path: external.jar but does it work for applets either?

Thanks for all.

EDIT: Or is there another way how to enclose external jar to an Applet? E.g. with HTML code?

Comment: What are you using to create the jar?  Both Maven and Ant allow manipulation of the manifest at packaging time.

Comment: *"But I'd like to re-create this app as Applet"*  Why?  It would be less hassle to distribute the current program using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  *"How could I edit manifest for enclosing the Driver to Applet?"*  Forget 'how'.  You should not be allowing direct access to the DB from either the desktop app. or applet.  Instead they should have to work through an interface that limits what they do.  Hence no 'driver' needs to be on the class-path of either.

Comment: BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @NickHolt: I use commandline.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I think it doesn't matter why I do it this way, I just need help with this.

Comment: *"I think it doesn't matter why I do it this way"*  It does matter if you want my help.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the command line, then just typing `jar` prints this:

[image]

Example 2 allows you to specify the file that will be used as the manifest.

Comment: Thanks, it was useful. I'm idiot I didn't look at these options.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to edit a manifest file inside a JAR file is as follows:

- change the extension of your JAR file to ZIP, e.g. test.jar just rename it to test.zip
- unzip your file
- edit your manifest file using a text editor, e.g. notepad++
- zip the contents of the unzipped folder
- rename it to test.jar

Comment: UnZipping or zipping (in Windows) will possibly break the jar because of class name collisions due to case (in)sensitivity. In Windows, `this.class` is the same as `This.class` but in Java it is not.

Comment: Which is a strong argument for not naming classes that way, yes?